# combine two sql update query into one query

Tags: sql, sql-update, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two update queries that I will like to combine into one query

```
UPDATE table_a DD
SET    DD.tomato = BH.tomato
       DD.juice = 'TRUE'       
FROM   table_b BH
WHERE  BH.guava = DD.guava
```

In the second update query, I want to set DD.banana to true where BH.guava = DD.guava and BH.title = 'Ripe'

```
UPDATE table_a DD
SET     DD.banana = 'True'    
FROM    table_b BH
WHERE   BH.guava = DD.guava
AND     BH.title = 'Ripe'
```

Any help will be appreciated...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Snowflakes, but any sql statement should work I guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional logic:

```
UPDATE table_a DD
    SET DD.tomato = BH.tomato
        DD.juice = 'TRUE',
        DD.banana = (CASE WHEN BH.title = 'Ripe' THEN 'True' ELSE DD.banana END)    
    FROM table_b BH
    WHERE BH.guava = DD.guava
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this makes sense. I will try this and give feedback....